# Back-convert a list (formatted as a string) into a list

Tags: python, list, dictionary, pandas

I have a list of dictionaries, it looks something like this:

```
[{'T': 13472}, {'A': 13472}, {'C': 9866, 'T': 3606}, {'G': 13472}, {'G': 13472}, {'A': 221, 'C': 26, 'T': 12845, 'G': 380}, {'T': 13472}, {'A': 13472}, {'C': 546, 'T': 12926}, {'C': 13472}, {'A': 13472}, {'C': 10674, 'T': 2798}, {'C': 13472}, {'A': 13472}, {'C': 554, 'T': 12918}, {'C': 13472}, {'A': 13472}]
```

The issue is right now, it's formatted as a string. In other words, when I try to iterate through the items in the list, I get only individual characters. Is there a way to convert it back into a "list of dictionaries" type?

Comment: Please give an exact example about how it is formatted now.

Comment: Imagine that list I wrote above, except formatted as a string. I doubt I could give anything more exact than what's in the qn. In any case, I saw `ast.literal_eval(string)`, and realized I could use that instead.  Thanks anyways!

Comment: I'm curious why you tagged this as `pandas`. Is this string `list`-of-`dict`s supposed to be valid JSON?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `ast.literal_eval` to convert a string to a python object(safely):

```
>>> from ast import literal_eval
>>> strs = "[{'T': 13472}, {'A': 13472}, {'C': 9866, 'T': 3606}, {'G': 13472}, {'G': 13472}, {'A': 221, 'C': 26, 'T': 12845, 'G': 380}, {'T': 13472}, {'A': 13472}, {'C': 546, 'T': 12926}, {'C': 13472}, {'A': 13472}, {'C': 10674, 'T': 2798}, {'C': 13472}, {'A': 13472}, {'C': 554, 'T': 12918}, {'C': 13472}, {'A': 13472}]"
>>> literal_eval(strs)
[{'T': 13472}, {'A': 13472}, {'C': 9866, 'T': 3606}, {'G': 13472}, {'G': 13472}, {'A': 221, 'C': 26, 'T': 12845, 'G': 380}, {'T': 13472}, {'A': 13472}, {'C': 546, 'T': 12926}, {'C': 13472}, {'A': 13472}, {'C': 10674, 'T': 2798}, {'C': 13472}, {'A': 13472}, {'C': 554, 'T': 12918}, {'C': 13472}, {'A': 13472}]
```

Comment: Ashwini, what a coincidence. I also saw the `literal_eval()` function on another post just after I posted this one. I will still up-vote and accept your answer anyways. Thanks!!!

Comment: `literal_eval` is earning its keep for you today Ashwini ;)

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean you have something like:

```
x = "[{'T': 13472}, {'A': 13472}]"
```

Then you could always simply evaluate it, assuming the source is safe.  Have a look at:

- http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.hatml#eval
- http://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval